# No Session Message on Frontend?

Tags: session

I have a very strange issue that looks related to session.

There are a couple of things not working:

- If I add a product to the cart, I'm redirect to the cart page but no items
- If I try to create a new user, I'm redirect back with no message.

I have tried the following code and I expect a message in the frontend but nothing:

```
public function anyAction()
    {
        $session = $this->_getSession();
        $session->addError($this->__('BLABLABLA'));
        $this->_redirectError(Mage::getUrl('*/*/create', array('_secure' => true)));
    }
```

That is why I suspect that the problem is related to session.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie cookie cookie !!!

Whenever you face similar issues crosscheck the `cookie domain` setting.

`System->Configuration->Web->General`

Comment: http://media2.giphy.com/media/whNK1SAMSQjwQ/200.gif

Comment: and clear your cookies / magento sessions to test (just to be sure)

Comment: setting right cookie domain in accord with the site domain was definitively the fix :)